# Run a function with a random list element

Tags: python, list, random

```
from roles import Herbalist, Warrior

def makeRolesAct(listOfTheRoles):
    y = 0
    for role in listOfTheRoles:
        print("Role", y, role.describe())
        print(role.act())
        y+=1

def main():
    listOfTheRoles = []
    listOfTheRoles.extend([Warrior('axe', 'dragon'), Herbalist(), Warrior('hammer', 'horse')])

    for x in range(5):
        makeRolesAct(listOfTheRoles)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`describe()` describes a role of the current actor. `act()` makes the actor do his action.

I'd like `makeRolesAct()` to run with a random `listOfTheRoles` element. 
So if I had the function in a loop it would repeat with actions repeating for randomly chosen actors.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum, tutorial or code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  You should spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module? Lots of stuff in there you can use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module.

```
...
import random
...

def makeRolesAct():
        role=listOfTheRoles[random.randint(0,4)]
        print("Role", role.describe())
        print(role.act())
...
...
```

Your code can be like above.